# Incremental Backup for PostgreSQL 8.3

Tags: backup, database, postgresql

I'm looking for a way to make good incremental backups for a large (more than 100 GB) PostgreSQL 8.3 DB. I'm currently using [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/app-pgdump.html) which isn't incremental and very slow in backup and restore, because it dumps the entire contents every time.

I thought [pg_rman](http://code.google.com/p/pg-rman/) would be the answer, but it's working on requires [PostgreSQL 8.4 or newer](http://code.google.com/p/pg-rman/issues/detail?id=12&colspec=ID%20Status%20Summary%20Type%20Priority%20Owner).

Any ideas?

Comment: You can try this tool for making scheduled backups http://postgresql-backup.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/pg-rman/

Appears to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a question better asked and answered on serverfault.com - in fact: https://serverfault.com/questions/55661/automatic-postgres-backup discusses a few options around backups.

What you probably want are online backups - have a look at the docs:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup-online.html

Comment: They discuss `pg_dump` and `pg_dumpall`, nothing incremental.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question